# Visualising $\pi_2(S^2)$ and $\pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spheres

I would like to know how to visualise the elements of $\pi_2(S^2)$ as *unit vector fields on the sphere*. For instance, the generator $a$ of $\pi_2(S^2)$ would be visualised as a 'hedgehog' configuration:
[image: enter image description here]]

(To be clear, I'm considering the grey sphere as the $S^2$ domain, and the red arrows as elements of the $S^2$ image, in classifying maps $f:S^2 \to S^2$. Considered in this way, all homotopy groups could be visualised as fields on spheres.)

I would like, in particular, to know what the vector fields are corresponding to the $a^2$ and $a^{-1}$ elements of $\pi_2(S^2)$. To me, this seems like an easier method of visualising this particular homotopy group than trying to imagine a sphere wrapped around another sphere a certain number of times, with self-intersections allowed, as in this image:

[image]

Likewise, viewing elements of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ as *undirected* unit vector fields, I would like to know how to visualise elements of $\pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^2)$ as vector fields on the sphere. My guess is that here the generator looks much like the 'hedgehog' above (without the arrow tips), but I am less sure of this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well can't we always just picture the vector field along the equator and then extend it the same way as you did for the hedgehog? I.e. we can consider a 2D arrow assigned to each point of the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. $a$ then corresponds to an arrow that rotates in the same direction and the same speed as its basepoint when you move around the circle. $a^2$ moves in the same direction but twice the speed as the basepoint, $a^{-1}$ in the reverse direction but the same speed and so on.

Comment: Visualizing homotopy equivalences as vector fields? That's the first time I've ever heard about such thing. How did you come up with the idea?

Comment: @freakish In general I tend to imagine the elements of $\pi_n(M)$ as $M$-valued fields on the $n$-sphere. I'm a physicist, so perhaps this is inspired by the application of these ideas to the study of topological solitons and topological defects.

Comment: @jabo It's not clear that we can always perform this extension that you describe. Furthermore, it may be that 'topologically equivalent' configurations on the circle become distinct when extended, whilst 'topologically distinct' configurations on the circle become equivalent when extended. For instance, consider the 'inwards pointing hedgehog'. This has the same winding number as the 'outwards hedgehog' when viewed along the equator, but doesn't seem to be equivalent on the whole sphere.

Comment: $\pi_2(S^2)$ is generated by the identity of $S^2$, and $\pi_2(\mathbb RP^2)$ is generated by the quotient map $S^2\to \mathbb RP^2$. You are trying to visualize this as a field by placing $v\in S^2$ on its image, but I am not sure this is always the best way to do it.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Perhaps this is not the best way to do it, although perhaps I have misled you. I am placing $v \in S^2$ not on its image, but on all points $p \in S^2$ such that $f(p) = v$.

Comment: @gj255 We want (equivalence classes) of *pointed* maps in $\pi_2$, so at one point of the sphere the vector field should always stay the same, say at a fixed point on the equator it should be normal. This means that the 'inward pointing hedgehog' is not a valid configuration. Extending planar vector fields along the equator to vector fields on the sphere should not be a problem: As you move from a point on the equator to the north pole along a geodesic you tilt the vector field upwards, changing its altitude until you reach the outward unit normal at the north pole. (tbc)

Comment: For the lower hemisphere you tilt it downwards until you reach the outward pointing normal at the south pole. This should give a continuous extension. Extending the unit normal along the equator in that way gives back the hedgehog. But admittedly it is not clear to me as well whether topologically distinct configurations on the equator stay topologically distinct after extending.

Comment: The hedgehog is the map $(\theta,\phi) \mapsto (\theta,\phi)$ in polar coordinates ($\theta$ the polar angle and all vectors assumed radius 1).  If that is a generator, then $(\theta,\phi) \mapsto (2\theta,\phi)$ is twice the generator.  This is the same as wrapping around twice, and you can replace $2$ with whatever integer you want.  This is basically what jabo said.